# What is Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

Actually I don't know about Arduino, but seeing my fellow classmates, I want to start learning it. Could anybody tell what actually Arduino is about?

Comment: Google Arduino or got to arduino.cc

Answer (score 1):

- [What is Arduino?](https://www.arduino.cc/)
- [Arduino video tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLT6rF_I5kknPf2qlVFlvH47qHvqvzkknd)
- [Official boards](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Products)
- [Wikipedia - Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino)
- [Arduino forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/)

---

A popular Arduino - The Arduino Uno:

[image: Arduino Uno]

---

In case I get accused of writing a "link-only" answer ...

The Arduino is a hobbyist prototyping platform, where users can develop projects for microprocessors. Typically the boards have one or two processors on them, can connect to a PC/Mac/Linux by a USB interface, be programmed in C++, and operate external devices (eg. motors, lights, MIDI, LCD screens, LEDs) and take readings (eg. temperature, time, location, voltage).

Different boards have different capabilities, such as the number of I/O ports, the amount of memory, and the size of the program that can be uploaded.

You can connect them to the major operating systems:

- Linux
- Macintosh
- Windows

The hardware and software are open-source, making development for them easy.

---

Image attribution: [Sparkfun Electronics](http://www.flickr.com/people/41898857@N04)